# How can I make PFQueryTableViewController return all data? Not just current user?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mobile, parse-platform

I subclassed PFQueryTableViewController, but It will only return the data for the currently logged in user. How can I make it retrieve data from all users?

### Code For the query

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
//if (self.objects.count == 0) {
//    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
//}

//[query orderByDescending:@"QuestionA"];
//[query whereKey:@"post" equalTo:@"0"];


//NSLog(@"%@",query);
return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-security/iOS) you can change a PFObject's permission on a per user or group basis - which the PFQueryTableViewController will abide by.  So if your table is only displaying objects for the current user it is probable that the objects were secured like:

```
object.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Before being saved to parse.  To allow an object to be read by all users you can set the permissions like so:

```
PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[acl setPublicReadAccess:YES];
object.ACL = acl;
```